# HTML5 Audio tag refuses to stop playing, even after being removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

So I have this audio tag:

```
<audio src=".....mp3" autoplay id="aud"></audio>
```

And 20 seconds later I fire this code:

```
var obj=$('#aud')
obj[0].volume=0;
obj[0].pause();
obj.prop('volume',0);
obj.trigger('pause');
obj.attr('src','');
obj.remove();
console.log('REMOVED!!');
```

But after all of this, the audio is still playing??

The audio tag has been successfully removed by `obj.remove()`, but the audio goes on.

The `console.log()` logs correctly. I get no errors. But despite using several methods to mute, pause and remove the audio tag, the audio goes on.

Can anyone explain why?

I need to purge this audio with salt and flame. Any help will be most appreciated, this is slowly sending me insane...

Comment: i think html is acting in retribution for your use of autoplaying media

Comment: the audio tag gets written to the page once someone hits a "play" button. i dont deserve the retribution, honest!

Comment: That should work... What browser? jQuery version? Maybe a jsfiddle with the issue ocurring?

Comment: I know it should work, and I cant re-create the problem in jsFiddle - which points to it being my code, but I need to understand what could be causing the audio to continue playing after it has been removed. Perhaps a better question should be "how can audio continue to play after the tag has been told to mute, pause and has been removed" - is there any cases of this ever happening? I am inspecting the DOM, and once removed there are no other audio tags anywhere in the page. I am using Firefox 28 and Chrome 25.

Comment: You wrote that you are manually appending the audio tag to the code. I belive the audio is being autoplayed even before you add the tag to the DOM and that messes up something (possibly startys the playback 2 times?). Try appending the audio tag to your DOM tree without the autplay property and simply calling `play()` on it after you add it

Comment: @xjedam that totally worked. Many thanks, add that as an answer and I'll mark you are correct.

Comment: @Jimmery sorry for the delay - been really busy. Added a sample and second possible solution in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I fiddled with this when writing this as an answer and I conclude the following:

Manually creating the `audio` tag with `autoplay` property causes it to play even before being added to the DOM tree 2 times(on older jquery implementations). Even after adding that element to the DOM tree, it will be usually impossible to stop both audio streams - prolly one of the streams gets disconnected from the element when second stream is played. Did not dig into that too deeply. I reproduced the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2gaBs/3/

When you click `Create w/o autoplay` button you can pause it properly, but when you click `Create autoplay` it will start immedietally (even before adding to the DOM tree) 2 times! You probably didn't notice the 2nd playback(neither did I) because when mp3 is on the same machine 2 audio streams are almost perfectly in sync. Pressing `Try stop` will stop one of the audio streams (you need to wait 5 seconds, note the setTimeout).

Also note that if you switch to jQuery ver to 1.8.3 or above this issue no longer occurs, so it seems that both of us were working on old jQuery libs that day^^

So 2 solutions are: update jquery version to 1.8.3 or above, or create the element without autoplay property and start it later.